# React functional component does not update conditional styling for Font Awesome icon

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, font-awesome

I can achieve conditional styling if I wrap the icon inside a `span` or `div` like this:

```
narrationIcon : {
    display: 'none'
}

<span className={`${props.narration ? '' : classes.narrationIcon}`}>
    <i className="fas fa-volume fa-2x"></i>
</span>

<span style={{ display: props.narration ? '' : 'none' }}>
    <i className="fas fa-volume fa-2x"></i>
</span>
```

However when used like this only the initial styling is set:

```
<i className="fas fa-volume fa-2x" style={{ display: props.narration ? 'inherit' : 'none'}}></i> 

<i className={`fas fa-volume fa-2x ${props.narration ? '' : classes.narrationIcon}`}></i>
```

Why is this? Is this due to Font Awesome generating `svg` under the hood?

Comment: are you using fontawesome npm module ?

Comment: Any reproducible example? https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq

Comment: @Dlucidone Nope, this is using vanilla Font Awesome but I'm still interested why it happens.

Comment: @DennisVash Tried to duplicate on code sandbox but there it worked as expected. Will investigate further and see if it can have something to do with Redux or something like that.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-ojosr?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Not redux, more for overriding CSS from a parent component.